# How to backtrace a function in python 2.7?

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7

I have a big python script, with multiple files, and I need to know where a method was called. Is there a backtrace function in python like debug_backtrace in php?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#module-traceback) module.

```
import traceback

def foo():
    bar()

def bar():
    baz()

def baz():
    traceback.print_stack() 
    # or trace = traceback.extract_stack()

foo()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to debug python

```
import pdb
```

then drop a

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

Where ever you would like to start debugging

see this site for more information

http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html